# SharePoint Online page layout - news webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, content-type, master-page, page-layout

my client wants to create 3 different news page layout, so when a user wants to create a page he can choose between those 3 layouts

I want to create a new page layout for the NEWS PAGES, This is what I have tried so far:

-I created a new content type

-I created a new page layout (on Sharepoint designer)

-I tried to create a new page using the created content type and page layout, but an error page occurred with no clear error message

(I activated site publishing features)

Link to the tutorial I followed : https://www.abelsolutions.com/taking-advantage-page-layouts-sharepoint/

Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint online modern news pages are nothing by Site Pages with 2 additional properties, PromotedState and FirstPublishDate. They are exclusive for News pages and essential for making a Site Page as News Page. News pages will have a PromotedState value 2.
I don't think it is now possible to override the news pages like the way you wanted. You can ofcourse create a child content type from SitePages but they won't have those above mentioned properties and hence the pages you create won't be marked as news.

Check the following article which provide details about news pages:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/what-makes-a-page-to-be-a-news-page-on-sharepoint-online/

Also, as per Microsoft roadmap, there is a new feature (id: 33136) coming up, which should let you handle the layout of SharePoint pages.

[image]

Comment: thank you for replying, so I can't create a custom news page layout! Do you have any other solution for my problem ?

Comment: @saharengazzou Can you please describe the original requirement which lead you to think of creating a new page layout?

Comment: My client wants to create 3 different news page layout, so when a user wants to create a page he can choose between those 3 layouts

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is possible with SharePoint modern news pages now. You will have to wait until the feature I have referred above to get deployed and see the possibilities it offers. You can check this article where someone says it's possible, but in that case it might not roll up as a news at all. [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Custom-page-layouts-default-content-for-Modern-Pages/td-p/89696). There is an user voice entry[link](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/20037172-page-layouts-in-modern-pages)

Comment: thank you for your time :)